# onTriggerEnter not called

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection

In unity 5, I am having a rigidBody and a trigger and the trigger has the tag name as "Goal"

Now on the rigidBody class I have this script -

```
void onTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    print ("test");

    if(other.transform.tag == "Goal") {         
        print ("test");
    }

}
```

But in the console I do not get "test" printed

The sources are [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9q1gz3emd8pbl8v/Assets%201.zip?dl=0)

The rigidBody properties-

[image]

The trigger properties-

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That's because it's OnTriggerEnter, with a captial "O".

Answer (score 0):

The function name is OnTriggerEnter not onTriggerEnter